# Filehelpers: Multiple delimiters in each row?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Can [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) parse into an object when there are multiple delimiters in each row of a file? Below is a sample row that I need to parse from a third party data provider using FileHelpers, if possible:

```
ItemID=1000|VerificationResult=ERROR|VerificationResultCode=-101|VerificationResultDetail=Duplicate ItemID|ProfileID=|ACHRouting=|ACHAccount=|LastFourCC=4444|InvoiceNo=731-021-36-572|DateTime=1/20/2016 1:04:30 PM|CustomField1=|CustomField2=
```

It would have been trivial with FileHelpers if the data provider had only used the pipe delimiter but as you see each key/value pair has an "=" between them then the pipe delimiter between each pair...sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`[FieldDelimiter]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910718/filehelpers-multiple-delimiters-in-each-row) attribute allows you to specify a different delimiter for a given field.

Another way would be to write your own converter for the key value pairs.

```
public class KeyValuePairConverter : ConverterBase
{
    private String _KeyName;

    public KeyValuePairConverter(String keyName)
    {
        // needs a parameter to get the export correct
        _KeyName = keyName;
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        // return everything after the last equals
        // (you could choose to validate the first part of the string against the _KeyName)
        return from.Substring(from.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);;
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}={1}", _KeyName, fieldValue);
    }
}
```

and then your field definitions would look like this

```
    [FieldConverter(typeof(KeyValuePairConverter), "ItemID")]
    public String ItemID;
```

Comment: Thanks shamp00! I don't use filehelpers enough to know that I could override and create my own converter. This is perfect, thanks.